# Thoughts and suggestions on my php SortFilesByDate function

Tags: php, file, function, sorting, date

I am fairly new to php and would love to hear your thoughts on this function I just wrote.
The idea is to sort an array of files chronologically from oldest to newest. Take a look and let me know if you think it can be improved at all:

```
function sortByDate($filearray){
    $OAR = array();
    foreach($filearray as $item){
        $OAR[filemtime($item)] = $item;
        }
    ksort($OAR);
    return explode(" * ", implode(" * ", $OAR ));
    }
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If more than one file has the same mtime, it will overwrite that file from your `$OAR` array.  Instead store each value as an array of files to solve that issue.

And this statement `return explode(" * ", implode(" * ", $OAR ));` seems like it can just be replace with `return array_values($OAR);`  With the above adjustment I mentioned, you may have to loop over the $OAR array and push each set of values to a new array and return that instead.

EDIT: here is an example.

```
function sortByDate($filearray){
    $OAR = array();
    $sorted = array();

    foreach($filearray as $item){
        $mtime = filemtime($item);
        if (!isset($OAR[$mtime])) $OAR[$mtime] = array();

        $OAR[$mtime][] = $item;  // push $item to the array for this mtime
    }

    ksort($OAR);

    foreach($OAR as $key => $values) {
        if (sizeof($values) > 1) sort($values); // sort by name
        foreach($values as $file) {
            $return[] = $file;
        }
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought about the possibility of the values being overwritten. Can you clarify what you mean by storing each value as an array?           Didn't know about array_values(), Thanks!

Comment: Gotcha, So this way, files of the same mtime "stack". Very Smooth.

Comment: You got it.  Losing files could be common because typically when files are unzipped, they may all get an mtime that is the same of within a few seconds depending how many files there were in the archive.

Comment: Certainly worth the extra loop at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

I would [`usort`](http://www.php.net/usort) it, for easy of use probably with [`SPLFileInfo`](http://www.php.net/SPLFileinfo) objects, but not strictly necessary... Avoid abusing keys for sorting if you can, it will often come back to bite ya.

```
usort($filearray,function($a,$b){
   return strcmp(filemtime($a),filemtime($b));
});
return $filearray;
```

Comment: Good to know php has this type of function built in, and then I would assume you loop through the array?

Comment: The only loop happening is internal in `usort`, without you seeing it. The code above would be the entire body of the function, no further loop necessary.

Comment: Wow, That is impressive. Thank you for making me aware of this.